# How to translate the language switcher links

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 8.1 the language switcher (block can be placed in a region) shows the languages labels in English:
English | German | French

I want to translate it. Visiting mysite/de the label should be in German:
Englisch | Deutsch | Französisch

mysite/fr --> labels should be translated in French

The words "German" and "French" and "English" are translated into all languages in my drupal installation. Yet the language switcher shows the labels in English all the way.

How translate it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for this same answer, but there is a way to translate them, so you can have them as English | Deutsch | Français in the language switcher for all languages: just translate the language name on /admin/config/regional/language

Answer (score 0):

Drupal => 8.1.10 (Launch sandbox)
**Choose language >Deutsch  (Save and continue)** 

[image: Choose language > Deutsch]
**Choose installation profile > Standard

Database configuration > (Save and continue)

Configure website > (Save and continue)

Update translations**

**Go to admin/config/regional/language and add English**

[image]
**German is the standard language**

**Then edit German: /admin/config/regional/language/edit/de. Change language name from German to De and save.**

**Then edit English: /admin/config/regional/language/edit/en.**
**Change language name from English**

**Got to /admin/config/development/performance and clear cache.**

**Then go to block layout and place the language switcher in any region.**

**Go to the website and check: The language switcher shows De English**